# My android app does not recognize R.string resources - what could be the reason?

Tags: android, android-resources

I learn android with sample apps from textbook. In the given sample source R.string.something is recognized:
[image: generic1]

However, in my own EXACT source code, same R.strings are not recognized- highlighted as errors:

[image: generic2]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: have you tried to rebuild your R class?

Comment: Stupid question: You *did* add `confirmMessage`, `cancel` and `delete` to your [string resource file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html), right?

Comment: Did you try clean + build app after adding resources?

Comment: Check **using** section. You may be using wrong R class.

Comment: check that you imported correct R class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this many time with eclipse, and it was not a setup / code problem on my side. Generally, cleaning, rebuilding and sometime even stopping and restarting eclipse solved it. And yes, it's a pain in the neck ...

Answer (score 2):

These are following reason possible.

1-: You import android.R;

2-: Any error in xml files.

3-: Please check you String.xml file may be any error or declare a string more then two time.

Answer (score 1):

Try a clean of your project, if that does nothing then click on the problems tab and see if there's any build related issues, you may be missing a required jar or something!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are new to Android.

If so, there are two ways of using text strings in Buttons, textviews and so on:

1) Hardcoded string - you put the text you want in quotation marks (""), for example:

```
yourTextview.setText("Hardcoded string");
```

2) You can call the text from your String resources (res/values/strings.xml). 
That is a much better approach seeing is is easier to translate, make changes and so on.

In your `strings.xml` file you can create all your string values, and call them from there.
Like in you example, if in your `strings.xml` file you have for example:

```
<string name="delete">This is String resource</string>
```

you can then call the string from there, like so :

```
yourTextview.setText(R.string.delete);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning or building the project didn't help me. Restarting the IDE did it in my case.